# mySQL and LAST_INSERT_ID issues

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a DB-Application and now we have to start with replication (master-master-replication).
We build a stored-function which returns an BIGINT. This value is unique on all involved servers.

The situation:
I have a table definition:

```
create table test (
 id BIGINT not null primary key auto_increment,
 col1 TEXT);
```

the table has a before insert trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_insert BEFORE INSERT ON test
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF NEW.id = 0 THEN
   SET @my_uuid = MYUUID();
   SET NEW.id = @my_uuid;
  END IF;
 END;
```

after an insert into test (col1) values ("foo") I need the value of the LAST_INSERT_ID() - but I only get the value "0".

I tried this in the trigger:

```
SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID(@my_uuid);
```

but it don´t work.

I read the mysql manpage which says, that all changes on last_insert_id within triggers and functions will be canceled at the end of the trigger.

So I try to avoid changing the application (which use php.last_insert_id())...

any ideas how to solve this without changing php-code?

greatings.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're trying to avoid an insert on the two masters ending up with the same ID.

One way to do this (assuming 2 masters) is to set [`auto_increment_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) to 2, and [`auto_increment_offset`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset) to 0 on one master, and 1 on the other.

This will result in ids on each master that cannot collide with the other.

Aside: with a bigint and random UUIDs, you current approach is likely to have a collision somewhere around 3 billion rows due to the birthday paradox.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `LAST_INSERT_ID` in mysql in relation to triggers is actually quite "un-standard" when compared to most other database server technologies. But I find it safer and much easier to work with.

Anyway, there's no one definite answer to you question, as replication is always complex. But the answer of `user83591` is sufficient to give you a solution for most cases. Notion of the birthday paradox is also very much in place. You should accept that as your answer.